# android parse xml from url

Tags: android, xml

I have android app and parser xml from url.
i was upload xml file to dropbox.
this is link https://www.dropbox.com/s/p6hvuywu2e81h9p/list_img.xml?dl=0
and I was upload xml file to google drive.
this is link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6FF5gPt_WxUQmpBWmRiLUUtR28/view?usp=sharing
but I can't parse it with this link.
how to change it like http://..../list_img.xml for parse xml from url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Links that you provided are links to the pages (Dropbox, Google Drive). They don't return "raw" xml. They return a full website page and just small part of the page is the content of your xml file. What you want is something like this: http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml where the content returned is only your xml.

Comment: I know, but how to change it with dropbox or google driver. or you know some website I can upload xml file with format you said ?

Comment: I know that you can view a raw file in GitHub. So if you have a github account just upload the file you need and there will be a "Raw" button. When you click on it, it opens url with a raw file content. You can try to use that url in your code. Not a very clean solution, but I don't have any other website in mind that can do it.. But prob there are plenty.